# Tweepy Status Error

Tags: python, django

I been trying to iterate over status, but I’m getting this error:

```
                Traceback <most recent call last>:
                     File “<console>”, line 2, in <module>
                NameError: name ‘process_status’ is not defined.
```

Below is the codes:

```
                from tweepy import Cursor
                for status in Cursor(api.user_timeline).items():
                    process_status(status)
```

What I’m I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: maybe function process_status is not imported?

Answer (score 2):

As highlighted by Jonas Heidelberg, one has to write her/his own `process_status` (or whatever name) function.

Say you're authenticated and your API instance (api) is constructed. Now, you want to print out the last 10 tweets in your timeline:

```
def process_status(sta):
    print(sta.text)

for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items(10):
            process_status(status)
```

It is as simple. And, it's a shame tweepy's documentation is so confusing (IMO).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking at [this tweepy documentation](http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/code_snippet.html)?

You **need to write that function**, `process_status`, **yourself** to do whatever you want with the `status`. If you have written it, it cannot be found by Python.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please give me some hint on how to go about it? I'm a newbie.